# how to authenticate mongoose connection mongodb in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have created mongodb user with command

```
use admin
db.createUser(
    {
      user: "superuser",
      pwd: "12345678",
      roles: [ "root" ]
    }
)
```

then in my app I am trying to connect mongoose like this

```
var options = {
user: "superuser",
pass: "12345678"
};


var mongooseConnectionString = 'mongodb://localhost/twitter-mongo';

mongoose.connect(mongooseConnectionString,options);
mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

var User = mongoose.model('User');
```

I am getting this error when inserting data through mongoose

```
MongoError: not authorized for insert on twitter-mongo.users
```

please tell me what is wrong in my code

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You must declare the authSource parameter in your connection string in order to specify the name of the database that contains your user's credentials:

```
var options = {
  user: "superuser",
  pass: "12345678"
};

var mongooseConnectionString = 'mongodb://localhost/twitter-mongo?authSource=admin';
```

Note: for users of Mongoose 4.x, you may want to also include `useMongoClient: true` in your *options* object. This silences the *Please authenticate using MongoClient.connect with auth credentials* and *open() is deprecated* error messages.

Comment: Thank you. I've been suffering for hours for this :)

Comment: The `useMongoClient` option is no longer necessary in mongoose 5.x, please remove it.

Answer (score 10):

This is working fine:

```
var options = { server: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1 } } };
var connectionString = 'mongodb://admin:admin1234@localhost:27017/myDB';

 mongoose.connect(connectionString, options);

//Add those events to get more info about mongoose connection:

// Connected handler
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function (err) {
  console.log("Connected to DB using chain: " + connectionString);
});

// Error handler
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});

// Reconnect when closed
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
   self.connectToDatabase();
});
```

Comment: This seems to be deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
const mongooseConnectionString = 'mongodb://superuser:12345678@ localhost/twitter-mongo?authSource=admin'
```

Answer (score 2):

I did run a mongo service using docker and then connected my mongoose to it with this code

```
const _database = 'mongodb://user:pass@localhost:port/MyDB?authSource=admin';
mongoose.connect(_database, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
})
.then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB ...'))
.catch(err => console.error('Could not connect to MongoDB:‌', err));
```

this is equal to

```
mongo --username user --password pass --authenticationDatabase admin --port 27017
```

on connection and then use `MyDB` database for doing operations like find, aggregate, insert and etc on it.

if you have no user (MongoDB default user) for your database then you can change `Database` like bellow:

```
const _database = 'mongodb://localhost:port/MyDB';
```

`27017` is default MongoDB port if your MongoDB port hasn't changed either then you can do the same for port too.
like bellow:

```
const _database = 'mongodb://localhost/MyDB';
```

this is the same as bellow:

```
mongo
```

above code is because there is no user and no port then for not been a user there is no need for authentication database either.

Answer (score 1):

```
mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://username:password@35.238.xxx.xxx:27017/dashboards?authSource=admin', {
   useNewUrlParser: true
}, (e) => {

    if (e) throw console.error('Error connecting to mongo database master');
    console.log('Connected to mongo database master.');

});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an User in database which you are operating on, not the admin DB.

Use this command,

```
use twitter-mongo;
db.createUser({
  user: "superuser",
  pwd: "12345678",
  roles: [ "root" ]
});
```

Instead of this,

```
use twitter-mongo
db.createUser({
  user: "superuser",
  pwd: "12345678",
  roles: [ "root" ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to create the connection string is
var connection = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://username:pwd@hostip:port/dbname?authSource=admin", options);

Please use authSource=admin to authenticate in connection string.