# Mongoose with Authentication causes timeout

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, mongoose

So we are having an interesting problem. We wanted to add authentication at the MongoDB Layer for more security. But we not getting a favorable outcome.

**Pre-Setup**

1. Use mongo shell (against admin table) as root
2. Switch to desired database (applicationdb)
3. Execute db.createUser()
4. Validate user was created successfully

   {
           "_id" : "applicationdb.appuser",
           "user" : "appuser",
           "db" : "applicationdb",
           "roles" : [
                   {
                           "role" : "readWrite",
                           "db" : "applicationdb"
                   }
           ]
   }

**Scenario 1:**

1. Change mongodb.conf, auth=true
2. Restart the Mongod service
3. Connect mongoose using:

   mongoose.connect('mongodb://appuser:password@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017/applicationdb');
4. No errors received for connect, so try to perform a GET through Mongoose causes the operation to timeout without any error (at least that I could find)

**Scenario 2:**

1. Change mongodb.conf, auth=false
2. Restart the Mongod service
3. Connect mongoose using:

   mongoose.connect('mongodb://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017/applicationdb');
4. No errors received for connect, so try to perform a GET through Mongoose and it returns documents successfully

Why do we get this timeout and never a completed request when using authentication in MongoDB?

Any help would be great, we're at a loss on this one!

Comment: Can you add the mongoose connect code, the options you have set.

Comment: @virattara, the code used is directly under step 3 in each scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restart the mongo service with the `--auth` option see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881208/how-to-put-username-password-in-mongodb)

If it doesn't works do this:
Try setting server options in mongoose with `keepAlive` set. See [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694824/how-to-authenticate-mongoose-connection-mongodb-in-node-js).

Comment: Thank you so much, --auth was the option that did it